# Application is not getting identified using CSS selectors working with Internet explorer browser version 11

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, browser-automation, selenium-iedriver

I am using "http://automationpractice.com/index.php" for POC on IE browser
when i navigated through "Sign In" button, this identification of Email text-boxes is going crazy and are being not identified by script.
I used CssSelectors for identification, below mentioned:

---

```
#email_create
input#email_create
input[id='email_create']
input[id*='email_create']
input[id^='email_create']
driver.findElement(By.CssSelector("MENTIONED ABOVE")).SendKeys("abc");
```

---

Surprisingly, these selectors worked for Chrome, Firefox but not in IE.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: i am able to find them, give error info. try xpath //input[@id='email_create']

Comment: Message: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : Could not find element by: By.XPath: //input[@id='email_create']

Answer (score 0):

I tried to test your code on my side with IE 11 browser.

In my test result, I found that your code is working and able to search the element using its ID.

I found that it shows the **OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException** error when I try to test your code using **CssSelector**

I tried to modify the code like below and it works with the IE browser.

```
   driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[id=email_create]")).SendKeys("abc");
```

Full code:

```
class Program
    {
        private const string URL = @"http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=authentication&back=my-account";

        private const string IE_DRIVER_PATH = @"D:\D drive backup\selenium web drivers\";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var options = new InternetExplorerOptions()
            {
                InitialBrowserUrl = URL,
                IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true,
                ForceCreateProcessApi = true,
                //BrowserCommandLineArguments = "-private"
            };
            var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(IE_DRIVER_PATH, options);

            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
            try
                {
                //var text = driver.FindElementById("email_create");
                //text.SendKeys("abc");

                driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[id=email_create]")).SendKeys("abc");

                Console.WriteLine("success");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }

        }
    }
```

Output:

[image]